# Flink Postgres query to jsonb column gives jdbc failure

Tags: python, java, postgresql, apache-flink, pyflink

I am using PyFlink 1.16 and flink-connector-jdbc-1.16.0.jar to query Postgres table with a jsonb column

```
sql = "SELECT entity_id FROM event_files"
table2 = table_env.sql_query(sql)
table2.execute().print()
```

It failed with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Doesn't support Postgres type 'jsonb' yet
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.dialect.psql.PostgresTypeMapper.mapping(PostgresTypeMapper.java:173)
```

I get this error despite not using the jsonb column.

I patched PostgresTypeMapper.java to map `jsonb` to `varchar`. Now the above code is working. But I want to query by jsonb column, payload. So I tried to cast it to varchar a column, P1:

```
sql = "SELECT entity_id, CAST(payload AS varchar) AS P1 FROM event_files"
table2 = table_env.sql_query(sql)
table2.execute().print()
```

but that fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.postgresql.util.PGobject is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader @38c50913; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.converter.AbstractJdbcRowConverter.lambda$createInternalConverter$224afae6$10(AbstractJdbcRowConverter.java:176)
```

I have been trying to find ways around this including creating a view from event_files, but nothing has worked so far.

#### Details on patching flink-connector-jdbc

Cloned the flink-connector-jdbc project from GitHub and add a few lines to flink-connector-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/jdbc/dialect/psql/PostgresTypeMapper.java:

```java
    private static final String PG_CHARACTER_VARYING_ARRAY = "_varchar";
    private static final String PG_JSONB = "jsonb";

            case PG_DATE_ARRAY:
                return DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.DATE());
            case PG_JSONB:
                return DataTypes.STRING();
```

I build it with Maven.

Comment: How did you patch PostgresTypeMapper.java? I tried to duplicate flink-connector-jdbc jar as a separate maven project. But I am facing many dependency issues.

Comment: Hi @Raghavendar, I could not really write code in comment so added patching details to question.